# How to add safely Angular Material to an existing angular application?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm trying to add Angular Material to my application. I installed Material components using this npm command

**npm install --save @angular/material @angular/animations @angular/cdk**

I had to update all my angular components to 7.0.2 version.
I added a new material module and referenced it from my app.module.js

material.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import {
  MatButtonModule,
  MatMenuModule,
  MatToolbarModule,
  MatIconModule,
  MatCardModule
} from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MatButtonModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatCardModule
  ],
  exports: [
    MatButtonModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatCardModule
  ]
})
export class MaterialModule {}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { AppRoutingModule } from "./app-routing.module";

import { MaterialModule } from './material.module';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';



@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, AppRoutingModule, HttpModule, FormsModule, MaterialModule, BrowserAnimationsModule],
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]

})
export class AppModule { }
```

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "angular-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "QuickStart package.json from the documentation, supplemented with testing support",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc -p src/",
    "build:watch": "tsc -p src/ -w",
    "build:e2e": "tsc -p e2e/",
    "serve": "lite-server -c=bs-config.json",
    "serve:e2e": "lite-server -c=bs-config.e2e.json",
    "prestart": "npm run build",
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run build:watch\" \"npm run serve\"",
    "pree2e": "npm run build:e2e",
    "e2e": "concurrently \"npm run serve:e2e\" \"npm run protractor\" --kill-others --success first",
    "preprotractor": "webdriver-manager update",
    "protractor": "protractor protractor.config.js",
    "pretest": "npm run build",
    "test": "concurrently \"npm run build:watch\" \"karma start karma.conf.js\"",
    "pretest:once": "npm run build",
    "test:once": "karma start karma.conf.js --single-run",
    "lint": "tslint ./src/**/*.ts -t verbose"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^7.0.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.0.2",
    "@angular/common": "~7.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.0.2",
    "@angular/core": "~7.0.2",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.0.2",
    "@angular/http": "~7.0.2",
    "@angular/material": "^7.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.0.2",
    "@angular/router": "~7.0.2",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.3.0",
    "angular-material": "^1.1.10",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.2",
    "systemjs": "0.19.40",
    "typescript": "^3.1.6",
    "typings": "^2.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.36",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.46",
    "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
    "concurrently": "^3.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.4.1",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "lodash": "^4.16.4",
    "protractor": "~4.0.14",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",
    "tslint": "^3.15.1"
  },
  "repository": {}
}
```

I cleaned node_modules and reinstalled everything to make I have all latest files. When I try to build my project I get all kind of errors. Mainly errors come from **\@angular\core** or **\@angular\common**

I spent too many hours and obviously I'm missing something because it shouldn't be so complicated.

["errors"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUuzu.png)

Comment: What was the Angular version previously you used? You can follow this guide to upgrade. https://update.angular.io/

Answer (score 0):

I can see two potential problems:

1. The release of Angular Material 7 now requires RxJS 6.3.
   You should update your RxJS package to `"rxjs": "~6.3.3"`. The syntax changed a bit, so have a look at this [update guide](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/v6/migration).
2. Have you included the base material theme file in your main `.scss` file as per this [step](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started#step-4-include-a-theme)?

Also, I don't think you meant to install the `"angular-material": "^1.1.10"`, package. Its for Angular.js. You can remove it.

Answer (score -2):

## Install Angular Material

Use the Angular CLI's install schematic to set up your Angular Material project by running the following command:

### ng add @angular/material

If need display MatSliderModule

You need to import the MatSliderModule that you want to display by adding the following lines to your app.module.ts file.

> import { MatSliderModule } from '@angular/material/slider';

```
 @NgModule ({....
 imports: [...,
 MatSliderModule,
 …]
 })
```

### Add the  tag to the app.component.html like so:

Run your local dev server:

ng serve
and point your browser to http://localhost:4200